# Accordion menu animation issues

Tags: jquery

I have created simple accordion menu based on one found jquery ui.I'm having issue's in animating the elements , when click i'm not able properly use  either slide up or down animations and lot of other issues crop up if it is used. So  any help would be greatful in getting animations.

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cZbr6/

Script

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var notfContainer = $('#notifications');

                notfContainer.find("a").each(function() {
                    var e = $(this);
                    if(!e.hasClass('active')) {         
                                e.next().css({
                                    'display':'none'
                                });     //hide all other div's and set height as 0px

                    }       
                });



                notfContainer.on('click' , function(event) {
                    var target = $(event.target);       //Used to find the element on which the click event has happened.

                    if(target.is("a")) {                //If the click event occurred on <a>
                        var self = $(target);           //Select the element
                        if(self.hasClass('active')) {   //If is is already expanded .. has active class
                            return;                     //just .. return 
                        }else {

                        notfContainer.find("a").each(function() {
                            var e = $(this);
                            if(e.hasClass('active')) {  
                                        e.removeClass('active');
                                        e.next().css('display','none');     //hide all other div's
                                        return false;   //break the loop    
                            }   


                        });
                            self.addClass('active');    
                            self.next().css({
                                'display':'block',
                                'height':'160px'
                            });


                        }


                    }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uzihef/edit#javascript,html,live)*

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#notifications a.active').next('div').siblings('div').hide();
  
    $('#notifications a').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
        var el = $(this).next('div');
        check = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : function(){ $('#notifications div').slideUp(); el.slideDown(); }();
    });
    
});
```